# Python - Using Set-Cookie on for cookie use not work

Tags: python, python-2.7, cookies, urllib2, urllib

When I get the Set-Cookie and try to use it, I wont seem that I'm logged in Facebook...

```
import urllib, urllib2

data = urllib.urlencode({"email":"swagexample@hotmail.com", "pass":"password"})
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.facebook.com/login.php", data)
request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla 5.0")

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
cookie = response.headers.get("Set-Cookie")
new_request = urllib2.Request("http://www.facebook.com/login.php")
new_request.add_header("User-Agent", "Mozilla 5.0")
new_request.add_header("Cookie", cookie)

new_response = urllib2.urlopen(new_request)
if "Logout" in new_response.read():
        print("Logged in.") #No output
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `Set-Cookie` header format is different from `Cookie` header.

`Set-Cookie` header contains additional information (doamin, expire, ...), you need to convert them to use it for `Cookie` header.

```
cookie = '; '.join(
    x.split(';', 1)[0] for x in response.headers.getheaders("Set-Cookie")
)
```

Even though you do above, you will still not get what you want, because default urllib2 handler does not  handle cookie for redirect.

Why don't you [use `urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor` as you did before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956080/python-using-cookies-successfully)

Comment: I already know how to use that, its just I need to learn how to do this properly also.

Comment: @user3818650, If you really want to do it without HTTPCookieProcessor, disable automatic redirect. Then handle redirect yourself (with proper cookie set).

Comment: @user3818650, FYI, [How do I prevent Python's urllib(2) from following a redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554446/how-do-i-prevent-pythons-urllib2-from-following-a-redirect)